# How to access a string resource from a simple class I created?

Tags: kotlin, android-studio, android-jetpack-compose

Trying to follow good practice of not hardcoding strings in my app, I'm wondering if it is possible to access the string resources from a very simple class which stores strings :

```kotlin
class myData {
val myString = getString(R.string.name)
}
```

So far, I'm using :

```kotlin
import android.content.Context
import com.example.myAppName.R

class MyData(val context: Context) {
val myString = getString(R.string.name)
}
```

And then using it in :

```kotlin
val context = LocalContext.current
val myData = MyData(context)
```

But it seems a bit convoluted : there must be a cleaner solution for such a trivial usecase ?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why would you prefer this over default approach, but if you want it, there are two possible approaches that are similar to what you want.

First approach:

```
    val Context.myString1
      get() = getString(R.string.my_string_1)

    val Context.myString2
      get() = getString(R.string.my_string_2)
```

It uses extensions on context but it does not group strings in one class

Second approach is similar and could be done like this:

```
val Context.my_string_1
    get() = MyStrings.my_string_1(this)

val Context.my_string_2
    get() = MyStrings.my_string_2(this)

object MyStrings {
    fun my_string_1(context: Context) = context.getString(R.string.my_string_1)
    fun my_string_2(context: Context) = context.getString(R.string.my_string_2)
}
```

It will create similar thing to yours, but again, it will use extension on context.

Looking at your code, I would strongly advice against capturing context like you are doing it as it can lead to leaks.
The way you are doing it that MyData class is created on each recomposition.

At the end, again, I think you should use existing composable:

```
/**
 * Load a string resource.
 *
 * @param id the resource identifier
 * @return the string data associated with the resource
 */
@Composable
@ReadOnlyComposable
fun stringResource(@StringRes id: Int): String {
    val resources = resources()
    return resources.getString(id)
}
```

Comment: Capturing context in a class is done in dozens of classes in the Android framework and is the reason for the AndroidViewModel class in Jetpack. It only leads to leaks if you don’t pay attention to which context you are passing and the lifetime of the class you are passing it to. You have to be aware of this anyway if you are using framework classes. But I agree that using `resources()` is the correct way in Compose. Your first suggestion with the extension on Context could be improved by making it an extension on Resources so it’s easily compatible with Compose.

Comment: @Милош Којадиновић : Thank you. I'm afraid even after following Android Basics for Jetpack Compose, this is quite difficult to grasp for a beginner like me. Would you please review my simplified usecase in the [following question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/78111199/13962899)?